# Views/Content - list all values of a field, even if not chosen in the node

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type for products. This has a (dropdown) field with values for each product. They choose a product and then enter the price for it.

If I want a view showing products that have been entered and their prices it works fine.

However, I want the view to show all products and their prices (if they have been entered).

e.g. I have available products: foo, bar, baz. There is a node for foo with a price of $10. No nodes for bar and baz yet.

My view shows: 
foo, $10.

What I want is for it to show

foo, $10
bar
baz

There isn't, by default, a relationship I can add (e.g. Content: Products).

What's my best bet?

Comment: why dont you change the dropdown field to taxonomy reference rather than a simple list. so that you can use the taxonomy to show the list.

Comment: Yes, that could work. It would be a mild pain but doable. It seems a bit OTT to leverage taxonomy for this purpose, but  if this is the only way of doing it, then I might do that.

Comment: I think it is better to use taxonomy for this. you can categories and do a whole lot of things with the product type.